# Union of continuous function on a topological space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ topological spaces, and $A,B\subset X$ such that $\overline{A}\cap B=A\cap \overline{B}=\emptyset$.

Suppose we have two continuous functions $f:A\to Y$, $g:B\to Y$.

> Is it true that the function $h:A\cup B\to Y$ defined as
>   $$h(x)=\begin{cases}f(x)& x\in A\\ g(x)& x\in B\end{cases},$$ is continuous?

I've tried taking $S\subset Y$ closed set and writing $h^{-1}(S)=f^{-1}(S)\cup g^{-1}(S)=(A\cap C_1)\cup (B\cup C_2)$ where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed subset of $X$, but I cannot conclude anything from this.

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X'=A\cup B$. Then from $\overline A\cap B=\emptyset=A\cap \overline B$ we can say, both $$A=X'\backslash \overline B=X'\backslash(\overline B\cap X')\text{ and }B=X'\backslash \overline A=X'\backslash(\overline A\cap X')$$ are open in $X'$ as, $\overline A\cap X'\subseteq_{\text{closed}}X',\overline B\cap X'\subseteq_{\text{closed}}X'$ . Now, for any open subset $V$ of $Y$ we have, $$h^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(V)\cup g^{-1}(V).$$ Since $f,g$ are continuous, we have, $f^{-1}(V)\subseteq_{\text{open}}A\subseteq_{\text{open}}X'$ and $g^{-1}(V)\subseteq_{\text{open}}B\subseteq_{\text{open}}X'$. So that, $h^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X'$.

Comment: Assuming closures are taken in $X$.